# Multiple border color issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

I am using -moz-border-top-colors for multiple border.
It works fine for Mozilla ,but
It does not work in other browsers.
however, I used -webkit ,still It did not work in Chrome.

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

this feature is supported by firefox only ... but you can use multiple shadows as a more cross-browser
solution

```
.box {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;

  /* custom borders */
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 green,
              0 -6px 0 0 black,
              0 -9px 0 0 yellow,
              0 -12px 0 0 skyblue;
}
```

check this link for more infos http://jsfiddle.net/8htrkqzb/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-border-top-colors this property is only supported in Firefox.